# Can't identify IP addresses

Tags: ip, nslookup

I got several interesting :) e-mails from IP addresses where I can't identify country and owner (internet provider), it's by example

```
10.180.221.97
10.220.113.130
10.52.135.39
```

I tried several IP lookup services with no luck. Please could you help me? Is it possible that IP doesn't have country identification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These addresses are coming from your private network or are somehow spoofed.

Addresses from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 are reserved for private networks (not connected to the internet)

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/addressing-the-lan.html

Answer (score 3):

Those IP Address will have no Country of Origin, as they are deemed Private Class A addresses.  From my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
#
# According to RFC 1918, you can use the following IP networks for private 
# nets which will never be connected to the Internet:
#
#       10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255
#       172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255
#       192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255
#
# In case you want to be able to connect directly to the Internet (i.e. not 
# behind a NAT, ADSL router, etc...), you need real official assigned 
# numbers.  Do not try to invent your own network numbers but instead get one 
# from your network provider (if any) or from your regional registry (ARIN, 
# APNIC, LACNIC, RIPE NCC, or AfriNIC.)
```

[RFC1918 - Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) - February 1996, updated by [RFC6761 - Special-Use Domain Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761) - February 2013.  These are the Standards that govern Private IP Addressing.  I'm posting this because this is how the person spoofing/masquerading is not getting caught, which airfishey beat me to.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `traceroute` of each IP address, to try and figure out their location.

Comment: -1 Please read both the selected answer and mine, to find out why this may not work... If the traffic is coming from inside his gateway the trace would stop at his gateway, but if the traffic is being spoofed this does no good...

Comment: Indeed, might not work.  But on the other hand it might reveal it to be on his own network.